# Time counting in c++ changes output based on the order of the commands instead of the actual proccesses

Tags: c++, time

!!!*SOLVED*!!!

I am trying to time some proccesses in my program but the output time depends on what order i write the commands to keep time instead of the actual time of the proccesses. For example if i do

```
auto start1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
for(int i =0;i < counter;i++)
    B.Search(randWords[i]);
auto finish1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

auto start2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
for(int i =0;i < counter;i++)
    A.Search(randWords[i]);
auto finish2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

cout<<"BST: "<<std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::TIME_UNIT>(finish1 - start1).count()<<" milliseconds"<<endl;
cout<<"AVL: "<<std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::TIME_UNIT>(finish2 - start2).count()<<" milliseconds"<<endl;
cout<<"Number of words searched: "<<counter<<endl;
```

The BST time will always be smaller than the AVL and if i put the AVL loop first its time will always be smaller than the BST's. Am i doing something wrong with how i count time?

I suspect what messes up with the accuracy of my program is the time it takes to print to the console. Both search methods also print the word it searches (and the randWords array contains up to 20000 words) and if i remove the print from my search methods the timekeeping is correct. Anything i can do about that?

Comment: What timings do you get for the different combinations?

Comment: I just ran a test where there were 17482 words searched and the BST's time is 159 milliseconds whereas AVL's time is 193 milliseconds. Now if i run a test but change the order of the BST loop and AVL loop the times i get are (for 20000 words): BST: 255 milliseconds, AVL: 200 milliseconds. Also if i comment out the print in the search methods i get very smaller times like 50-60 milliseconds for 20k words.

Comment: There's nothing that can be done about console output having measurable, or skewed, effects on benchmarking. To measure console output as being completely instantaneous, and no effects on benchmarking would involve, I'm afraid, breaking some fundamental laws of physics of our shared universe, so it's very unlikely to happen any time soon. Perhaps you can log some diagnostics into a buffer, and only output it at the end of the benchmarked portion.

Comment: The variance across runs seems to be a lot more than the difference between the algorithms. You should use some micro-benchmarking tool for this.

Comment: The thing is that the console output time is not being measured equally. Both loops print the same amount of words but my console is looking like it skips most of the words and only prints the last few hundreds of them, so the second for loop will always be burdened with more time

Comment: You perform a search but do not do anything with its result. Optimizing the code might eliminate all actions entirely. Performing tests in non-optimized mode is inherently meaningless.

Comment: I managed to fix the problem by writing the output in two seperate files instead of printing it out to the console. Now the times seem to be correct and not affected by the order of the loop commands. Thank you everyone for your time.

Comment: If you have solved the issue maybe it would be helpful to provide an answer with information about how you did it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem by writing the output in two separate files instead of printing it out to the console. Now the times seem to be correct and not affected by the order of the loop commands.